# Length filter on django template doesnt seem to work

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use raw query instead of the ORM. However I am having trouble when i try to count all instances from MyTable.

Below is the code from my view :

```
problems_raw_count = MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM MyApp_MyTable')
problems_count = list(problems_raw_count)
```

And now the variable I am trying to implement on template side :

```
{{ problems_count|length }}
```

I know I could simply use **MyModel.objects.all()** but it does interest me to know why it is not actually working.

Many thanks.

Romain

Comment: forgot to say "Hi".. So Hi everyone !

Comment: This looks like it should work. What output do you get when you `print(problems_count)`? Are you seeing a list of results?

Comment: Did you pass `problems_count` to the *context* of the *template*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes it is passed..

Comment: @FlipperPA, Yes I am seeing results.. I have a proper list, for instance [<MyModel : First Subject>, <MyModel : Second subject>, ... ]